# Where to find source code of List.Map in F# module List?

Tags: f#

I am searching for the source code of the function `List.map` provided by the F# core library. What I did find by looking on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L75-75) was this:

```
  [<CompiledName("Map")>]
  let map mapping list = Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map mapping list
```

But here I'm stuck - I can't seem to get a look at `Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map`.

Can anybody point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation is defined here:
https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L245

Comment: It would be handy if there was a link from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L75-75) to this page

Comment: Now here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L240